# Text overflow input field and placeholder issue in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

my html,

```
<input autofocus="autofocus" id="home_email_input" maxlength="85" name="username" placeholder="E-mail" type="text">
```

my css,

```
#home_email_input {
margin-left: 22px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 154px;
padding-left: 30px;
background: url(http://s23.postimg.org/rsc76su0n/envelope.gif) no-repeat scroll 4px 3px;
}
```

demo,

http://jsbin.com/OZALEdo

as you can see, if the user type long word, in chrome it works fine,

but in `IE8` i have two issue,

- if the text gets long, it trasspass the icon area. the padding doesn't work
- placeholder doesn't work.

I'll be waiting for a good solution. Thankyou!

**Don't tell me that the user have to update the browser. My LOVELY client wants IE8!!!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the text gets long, it trasspass the icon area. the padding doesn't work

Put the icon *next* to the field. Remove the border from the field. Put a border on an element that contains both the field and the image.

> placeholder doesn't work.

Use a `<label>` next to the field. `placeholder` is explicitly not for describing the purpose of the field. It is for hints and examples.

```
<label> Email <input placeholder="bob@example.com"> </label>
```